# C# Call One Microservice from another MicroService

Tags: c#, microservices

I want to call one microservice from another service. I am developing these services in C# and deploying in lambda. Here is my scenario. I have a Coupon service and a customer service.

UI calls the coupon service to check if the customer is eligible for a customer with customer id and coupon id.

Coupon service needs to call the customer service to get the customer details even before any coupon business logic happens.

My question is, can I call the customer service from the action filter of the coupon service so the customer details will be retrieved before the controller call and necessary customer details will be available?

Is this a good coding practice?

Comment: Why not simply call the other service as part of the action?

Comment: Or, if you are worries about performance, you may get all customers details at startup and keep a local copy cached.

Comment: Hi @Alejandro , Thanks for your response. This can me called from the action method itself. My worry is, do we have any specific standards , architecture principle available in order to call one microservice from another. I see the question is closed as it is generic, I will also try to rephrase the question with examples for more clarity.